# How to draw cube (3D plot) with dashed lines instead of solid lines in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-styles

A figure of a cube (or a 3D plot), along with an external image, is shown below (and its code is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516987/adding-external-graphic-as-plane-in-3d-plot)). I'm trying to use dashed lines instead of solid lines in this figure. I have checked these links, [link2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501309/3d-cube-with-dashed-lines-and-faces-filled), [link3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136836/dashed-axis-lines), and [link4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45275/tikz-get-values-for-predefined-dash-patterns), but I need help to solve this problem.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
enlargelimits=false,
axis on top,
axis equal image,
xmin=0,xmax=4,
ymin=-1,ymax=1,
zmin=-1,zmax=1,
ylabel=$X$,zlabel=$Y$, %xlabel=$Z$,
view={-20}{30},
xtick={0, 4},
ticks = none,
clip = false,
]

\draw [black,dashed] 
(axis cs:?) -- (axis cs:?)  % ???
(axis cs:?) -- (axis cs:?);

\path (axis cs:0,0,0) coordinate (O) (axis cs:1,0,0) coordinate (X)  
(axis cs:0,1,0) coordinate (Y) (axis cs:0,0,1) coordinate (Z)
 (axis cs:4,0,0) coordinate (P)  
 [x={($(O)-(X)$)},y={($(O)-(Y)$)},z={($(Z)-(O)$)},
    canvas is yz plane at x=0,transform shape]
   (P) node{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image-duck}};


\path (axis cs:0,0,0) coordinate (O) (axis cs:1,0,0) coordinate (X)  
(axis cs:0,1,0) coordinate (Y) (axis cs:0,0,1) coordinate (Z)
 (axis cs:0,0,0) coordinate (P)  
 [x={($(O)-(X)$)},y={($(O)-(Y)$)},z={($(Z)-(O)$)},
    canvas is yz plane at x=0,transform shape]
   (P) node{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image-duck}};


%\draw[black, <->] ([xshift =-0.09cm] axis description cs:0, 0.2) -- node[left] {} ([xshift =-0.1cm] axis description cs:0, 0.66) node[font=\scriptsize, midway, left=-1mm] {\fontsize{6.5}{6.5}\selectfont$y$};
%\draw[black, <->] ([xshift =-.14cm] axis description cs:0.01, 0.19) -- node[left] {} ([xshift =-.39cm] axis description cs:0.35,- 0.01)node[font=\scriptsize, midway,below] {\fontsize{6.5}{6.5}\selectfont$x$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please include code for your minimal example here. Aside from anything else, you haven't said *which* code you're using from the link you gave. Could you explain about the cube? The linked question and answers concern plots, so there are axes etc. and that's what you seem to show as well. Is this a plot? Which cube are you talking about? (Or cuboid??) In general, you can just add `dashed` to the `\draw` commands to get dashed lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really clear what you're trying to do or how whatever you've tried hasn't worked, but maybe something like this ...

[image: dashed lines before and behind duck]

There are zero cubes in this answer, though.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705675/ addaswyd o ateb user194703: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516994/
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{%
  every axis/.append style={%
    draw=lightgray
  },
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      enlargelimits=false,
      axis equal image,
      xmin=0,xmax=4,
      ymin=-1,ymax=1,
      zmin=-1,zmax=1,
      xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,zlabel=$z$,
      view={-20}{30},
      xtick={0, 3},
    ]
    \draw [red,dashed] 
      (axis cs:0,1,1) -- (axis cs:4,1,1) 
      (axis cs:0,1,-1) -- (axis cs:4,1,-1);
    \path (axis cs:0,0,0) coordinate (O) (axis cs:1,0,0) coordinate (X)  
    (axis cs:0,1,0) coordinate (Y) (axis cs:0,0,1) coordinate (Z)
    (axis cs:3,0,0) coordinate (P)  
    [x={($(X)-(O)$)},y={($(Y)-(O)$)},z={($(Z)-(O)$)},
    canvas is yz plane at x=0,transform shape]
    (P) node{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image-duck}};
    \draw [red,densely dashed] 
      (axis cs:0,-1,1) -- (axis cs:4,-1,1) 
      (axis cs:0,-1,-1) -- (axis cs:4,-1,-1);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question and inserted its related code. I used `draw` without `\pgfplotsset{%
  every axis/.append style={%
    draw=lightgray
  }` . Also, I had a problem with the setting of cs().

Comment: @Ellie You should be able to adapt the above either way. The main thing is to split the lines so you get the back ones behind the picture and the others in front.